# Default rate short majurity

Tags: credit-risk, default-probability, default, default-risk

**What is the best way of measuring default rates for a portfolio which contains mostly loans which are either 30, 60 or 90 days term?**

Normally I use the following methodology

[image]

Look at all loans which are in the portfolio on a specific date. Any loan which does not default within the next 12 months is a `Good` loan irrespective if the loan ends within those 12 months or not. Any loan which defaults within those 12 months is a `Bad` loan. Loans which start within the 12 months are disregarded.

What is the best way of doing this?

- Keep everything the same way
- Scale down from 12 months to 90 days and multiply resulting default rate by 4.
- Other suggestions?

Comment: A simple approximation would be to downscale the PD as $1-(1-PD(0,T))^{t/T}$.

Comment: I would change the observation period to 3 months and then use the formula to upscale to 12 months (12 months is what i need for reporting and regulatory purposes). Makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that could work as well. Effectively, if your PDs are quite small, you'll see that the annualized PD is of course roughly $PD(0,1) \approx 4 \times PD(0,0.25)$.